# PowerShell file upload with PhoneGap not retrieving page

Tags: powershell, http-status-code-404, webclient

I am trying to upload an archive file (a Zip archive if that matters) to an existing API at an external site and while I can get the webclient to connect and get a token to the site the upload never seems to work, I continually get a 404 error.  The problem may be on their side, but I seem to be the only one who has posted about it on their site, yet I wonder if I am using the UploadFile correctly, or if there is a way to capture the response from the command, which I'd like to know if only to improve my PowerShell coding.

What I am running is the following:

```
# Variables I want to use
$appArchive = "\\networkpath\Releases\CodeReleasePackage.zip"
$localArchive = "c:\temp\CodeReleasePackage.zip"
[string]$appUrl = "https://site.com/api/v1/apps/(id)/"
[string]$tokenUrl = "https://site.com/token"
[string]$uploadUrl = "https://site.com/api/v1/apps/(id)/?auth_token=$mytoken"
# $appCred = Get-Credential
$username = "email@address"
$password = "password"
# Create the web client
"Creating the client.`n"
$pgup = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$pgup.Credentials = New-Object net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)
"Going to the token page"
$pgToken = $pgup.UploadString($tokenUrl,"")
$mytoken = $pgToken -replace '{|}|"|:|token',''
"Now trying to upload the latest file with my token: $mytoken"
$pgup.UploadFile($uploadUrl,$appArchive)
```

I get the token which is something like {"token","hkjuihgkjhiuhhlkhuhk"} and not really knowing if there is a better way to handle the resulting token I did the replace to get rid of everything but the token string.  Adding it to the URL is supposed to work but I just get 404 errors accorinding to Fiddler.

So I'd like to be able to capture the response from the site when I run $pgup.UploadFile() but when I do it seems like nothing is coming back, is there a particular way to capture that?  I couldn't find a clear example and when I do something like $response = $pgup.UploadFile() I have nothing in $response.  Anything that is useful for diagnosing webclient errors would be great, I'd like to learn more about this since it seems pretty useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I cannot access the site with PowerShell as the driver, for some reason I can never get the upload to work but I can read the pages on the site and actually get responses for my account.  It may be their API doesn't like the way PowerShell is running the connection, although I have never been able to confirm anything from PhoneGap since they have not yet responded to my issues on this yet.

Edited: 6/14/12
The whole reason this was failing was due to the Apache implementation on their side not accepting the HTTP 1.1 request the way WebClient sends it.  If I can get back to HTTP 1.0 then they say I should be able to complete this.  Or I can wait for the OAUTH 2.0 implementation and just go from there.

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure if this is what your looking for, however here is a bit of code that I use to upload a zip file to a server.

```
$File = "yourfile.zip" #File to be uploaded
$ftp = "ftp://yourserver/directory #Location for the zip file to be uploaded


$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp)
$webclient.Credentials =  Get-Credential #Will prompt for user info. You can use your above way to gather credentials as well
$webclient.UploadFile($uri,$File)
```

As you can see its rather short and simple, and almost identical to your code but does not handle tokens.

Comment: A good example thanks, at least I know I am doing it the right way.